# Edição simples de registro com PHP+MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Basicamente os três *scripts* deveriam editar um registro no Banco de Dados:

registros.php:

```html
<?php

// Aqui você se conecta ao banco
$mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'login');

// Executa uma consulta 
$sql = "SELECT `user_id`, `user_name` , `user_email` , `user_data` FROM `users`";
$query = $mysqli->query($sql);
while ($dados = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
 $id        = $dados["user_id"];
 $nome      = $dados["user_name"];
 $email = $dados["user_email"];
 $data = $dados["user_data"];
 
 echo "<a href=\"editar.php?id=$id\">Editar </a>";
 
 
}


?>
```

editar.php:

```html
  <?php

// Aqui você se conecta ao banco
$mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'login');

// Executa uma consulta 
$sql = "SELECT `user_id`, `user_name` , `user_email` , `user_data` FROM `admin_users`";
$query = $mysqli->query($sql);
while ($dados = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
 $id        = $dados["user_id"];
 $nome      = $dados["user_name"];
 $email = $dados["user_email"];
 $data = $dados["user_data"];
 
 echo "
 <form id=\"form1\" name=\"form1\" method=\"post\" action=\"salvar_edicao.php\">
 <input name=\"id\" type=\"text\" readonly=\"readonly\" id=\"id\" value=\"$id\" size=\"35\"/><br>
 <input name=\"nome\" type=\"text\" id=\"id\" value=\"$nome\" size=\"35\"/><br>
 <input name=\"email\" type=\"text\" id=\"id\" value=\"$email\" size=\"35\"/><br>
 <input name=\"data\" type=\"text\" readonly=\"readonly\" id=\"id\" value=\"$data\" size=\"35\"/><br>
 <input type=\"submit\" onclick=\"return confirm('Deseja mesmo editar esse registro?');\" name=\"Submit\" value=\"SALVAR ALTERAÇÕES\" class=\"btnNew\"/>
 </form>
 ";
 
 
}


?>    
 
</div></div>
```

salvar_edicao.php:

```html
<?php
$id      = $_POST["id"];
$nome = $_POST["nome"];
$email     = $_POST["email"];
$data      = $_POST["data"]; 

// Aqui você se conecta ao banco
$mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'login');

mysql_query("UPDATE users SET user_name = '$nome', user_email = '$email' WHERE users.id = $id");
mysql_close();
header("Location: index.php#tabs-4");
?>
```

Não altera. O que está errado?

Comment: Observe que o seu arquivo salvar_edicao.php cria uma conexão com MYSQLI ($mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'login');) e o update tenta atualizar com o MYSQL (mysql_query("UPDATE users SET user_name = '$nome', user_email = '$email' WHERE users.id = $id");)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em salvar_edicao.php faça a rotina de atualização chamando a API correta mysqli e não a antiga mysql_*

Mude:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET user_name = '$nome', user_email = '$email'
             WHERE users.id = $id");
```

Para:

```
$mysqli->query("UPDATE users SET user_name = '$nome', user_email = '$email'
             WHERE users.id = $id");
```

Pode evitar o problema de [sql injection](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3864/91) utilizando prepared statements:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE users SET user_name = ?, user_email = ? WHERE users.id = ?';
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

if(!$stmt){
  echo 'erro na consulta: '. $mysqli->errno .' - '. $mysqli->error;
}

$stmt->bind_param('ssi', $nome, $email, $id);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Exibiu o erro: Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\login\admin\salvar_edicao.php on line 17

Comment: @Renan, significa que tem um erro na consulta.

Comment: @Renan, pode colocar o seu código no comentário.

Comment: <?php
$id      = $_POST["id"];
$nome = $_POST["nome"];
$email     = $_POST["email"];
$data      = $_POST["data"]; 

// Aqui você se conecta ao banco
$mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'login');

$sql = 'UPDATE users SET user_name = ?, user_email = ? WHERE users.id = ?';
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

if(!$stmt){
  echo 'erro na consulta: '. $mysqli->errno .' - '. $mysqli->error;
}

$stmt->bind_param('ssi', $nome, $email, $id);
$stmt->execute();
?>

Comment: Mude a linha do prepare() para `$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql) or die($mysqli->error);`. @Renan e veja se aparece algum erro.

Comment: Deu certo com a nova linha

Comment: Apareceu algum erro? @renan

Comment: Não, nenhum erro.

Answer (score 0):

Código completo corrigido:

registros.php:

```html
<?php

// Aqui você se conecta ao banco
$mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'login');

// Executa uma consulta 
$sql = "SELECT `user_id`, `user_name` , `user_email` , `user_data` FROM `users`";
$query = $mysqli->query($sql);
while ($dados = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
 $id        = $dados["user_id"];
 $nome      = $dados["user_name"];
 $email = $dados["user_email"];
 $data = $dados["user_data"];
 
 echo "<a href=\"editar.php?user_id=$id\">Editar</a>";
 
 
}


?>
```

editar.php:

```html
  <?php

// Aqui você se conecta ao banco
$mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'login');
$id = $_GET["user_id"];
settype($id, "integer");

// Executa uma consulta 
$sql = "select * from users where user_id = $id";
$query = $mysqli->query($sql);
while ($dados = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
$id        = $dados["user_id"];
$nome      = $dados["user_name"];
$email = $dados["user_email"];
$data = $dados["user_data"];}


?>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="salvar_edicao.php">
<input type="text" readonly name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $id;?>" /><br>
<input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" value="<?php echo $nome;?>" /><br>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>" /><br>
<input type="text" readonly name="data" id="data" value="<?php echo $data;?>" /><br>

<input type="submit" onClick="return confirm('Deseja atualizar o registro?');" name="Submit" value="SALVAR ALTERAÇÕES" id="button-form" />
 </form>
 
</div></div>
```

salvar_edicao.php:

```html
<?php
@ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$id        = $_POST["id"];
$nome      = $_POST["nome"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$data     = $_POST["data"];

// Aqui você se conecta ao banco
$mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'login');

$sql = 'UPDATE users SET user_name = ?, user_email = ? WHERE users.user_id = ?';
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql) or die($mysqli->error);

if(!$stmt){
  echo 'erro na consulta: '. $mysqli->errno .' - '. $mysqli->error;
}

$stmt->bind_param('ssi', $nome, $email, $id);
$stmt->execute();
header("Location: index.php#tabs-4");
?>
```